# Does loot degenerate when breaking chests?

Tags: neverwinter-nights

Neverwinter Nights has a *lot* of locked chests, and it is kind of tedious to unlock (or have a henchman or familiar unlock) a chest when it would take a single bash or spell to break it. But does breaking chests somehow change the loot in it for the worse, like in some other games? It would take a bunch of testing to settle this, but I'm sure someone has already done it and my search-foo just isn't up to it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it tells you this in the tutorial about locked chests.  And that you get broken items when you bash them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, items do not get broken, you can bash to your hearts content. See [here](https://forum.rpg.net/archive/index.php/t-207702.html) and [here](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/188666-neverwinter-nights/60899747).

However it is perfectly possible to script mods to destroy items, when you bash chests. So, your experience may differ with a mod.